# If substring in string, replace string with number

Tags: python

I have the following mapping

```
mapping = {'sum12':2, 'sum6':1,
            'avg12':2, 'avg6':1,
            'diff':3, 'mean':4}
```

and I have a dataframe with variables like

```
        var1      var2
0  abc_sum12  mean_jkl
1   pqr_sum6  pqr_avg6
2   diff_xyz    qwerty
```

If any of the substrings are present in the strings in the dataframe, I want to replace them with their corresponding values. If no substring is present, I want to replace it with `np.nan`. At present, the only solution I can think of is going through every row, checking if any of the substrings is present in every string, and replacing it with the specific number corresponding with that substring. Is there a better way to do it.

The output in the end would be

```
   var1  var2
0     2   4.0
1     1   1.0
2     3   NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe if you replace using regex, it will partial match and give you the result you want.  The only exception is the `qwerty` value which will remain unchanged.  If you then coerce the entire df to numeric, it will return `NaN` for that value or any other non-numeric.

```
import pandas as pd
mapping = {'sum12':2, 'sum6':1,
            'avg12':2, 'avg6':1,
            'diff':3, 'mean':4}

df = pd.DataFrame({'var1': ['abc_sum12', 'pqr_sum6', 'diff_xyz'],
 'var2': ['mean_jkl', 'pqr_avg6', 'qwerty']})

df = df.replace(mapping, regex=True).apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))

print(df)
```

output

```
   var1  var2
0     2   4.0
1     1   1.0
2     3   NaN
```

Comment: I didn't know about df.replace, neat!

Comment: I didn't know about it either. That's pretty helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
mapping = {'sum12':2, 'sum6':1,
            'avg12':2, 'avg6':1,
            'diff':3, 'mean':4}

df = pd.DataFrame(
{'var1': {0: 'abc_sum12', 1: 'pqr_sum6', 2: 'diff_xyz'},
 'var2': {0: 'mean_jkl', 1: 'pqr_avg6', 2: 'qwerty'}})

df_new[:] = np.nan
df_new = df_new.astype('float')

for name,col in df.items():
    for key,val in mapping.items():
        df_new[name][col.str.contains(key)] = val
```

The resulting dataframe `df_new`:

```
   var1  var2
0   2.0   4.0
1   1.0   1.0
2   3.0   NaN
```

Comment: This works as well, but I was looking at transforming the entire df rather than going row by row. Thanks though!

Comment: @Tejas Technically, we're going column-by-column rather than row by row. In any case, you're welcome.

Comment: Oh right, sorry. In that case, this would work pretty well too!